# Sum of a number's digits with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, sum

I have:

```
var nums = [333, 444, 555];
```

I want to treat each digit in a number as a separate number and add them together. In this case sums should be:

```
9 = 3 + 3 + 3
12 = 4 + 4 + 4
15 = 5 + 5 + 5
```

How to achieve this using JavaScript?

Answer (score 8):

you can use a simple modulo operation and dividing

```
var a = [111, 222, 333];

a.forEach(function(entry) {
    var sum = 0;
    while(entry > 0) 
    {
        sum += entry%10;
        entry = Math.floor(entry/10);
    }
    alert(sum)
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Here’s a different approach that converts the numbers to strings and converts those into an array of characters, then the characters back into numbers, then uses `reduce` to add the digits together.

```
var nums = [333, 444, 555];
var digitSums = nums.map(function(a) {
  return Array.prototype.slice.call(a.toString()).map(Number).reduce(function(b, c) {
    return b + c;
  });
});
digitSums; // [9, 12, 15]
```

If your array consists of bigger numbers (that would overflow or turn to `Infinity`), you can use strings in your array and optionally remove the `.toString()`.

Comment: A slight variant `[333, 444, 555].map(function(d) { return d.toString().split('').reduce(function(acc, c) { return acc + parseInt(c,10); }, 0) })` , to illustrate `d.toString().split('')` as an alternative way to get the list of letters in  string.

Comment: @widged You’re right… I got used a bit _too_ much to the ES6 spread operator where you could do `[...'String']` to get `['S','t','r','i','n','g']` or `Array.from` that I assumed it was fine to just use `Array.prototype.slice.call` everywhere as a replacement.

Answer (score 1):

Now in our days, with the advantages of **ES6**, you can simply [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) each value of your array inside `map`, and the with `reduce` make the operation:

```js
var numbers = [333, 444, 555];

const addDigits = nums => nums.map(
      num => [...num.toString()].reduce((acc, act) => acc + parseInt(act), 0)
);

console.log(addDigits(numbers));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var nums = [333, 444, 555]; 

nums.map(number => [...String(number)].reduce((acc, num) => +num+acc , 0));


//output [9, 12, 15]
```

Unary plus operator (+num) is converting string into integer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generate an array consisting of the sum of each digit, you can combine the [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)/[`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) methods. The `.map()` method will create a new array based on the returned value (which is generated on each iteration of the initial array).

On each iteration, convert the number to a string (`num.toString()`), and then use the `.split()` method to generate an array of numbers. In other words, `333` would return `[3, 3, 3]`. Then use the `.reduce()` method to add the current/previous numbers in order to calculate the sum of the values.

```js
var input = [333, 444, 555];

var sumOfDigits = input.map(function(num) {
  return num.toString().split('').reduce(function(prev, current) {
    return parseInt(prev, 10) + parseInt(current, 10);
  }, 0);
});

//Display results:
document.querySelector('pre').textContent =
  'Input: ' + JSON.stringify(input, null, 4)
   + '\n\nOutput: ' + JSON.stringify(sumOfDigits, null, 4);
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```